# Ruby on rails redirect_to won't redirect after save, just stays on page (but does save)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

   def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])     
      respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to :success }  

      else

      format.html { render :new }  
      format.js   { render :form_errors }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

View:

```
<div id="joinFormContainer"> 
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true do |f| %>
      <div id="firstNameField">
       <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First Name" %>
      </div>
      <div id="lastNameField">
   <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last Name" %> 
      </div>
      <div id="emailFieldJoin">
   <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email"  %>
      </div>

      <div id="passwordFieldJoin">
   <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password"  %>
      </div>
      <div id="usernameField">
   <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Username"  %>
      </div>

      <div id="joinButton">      <%= f.submit 'Join Us', :id =>"join_submit" %> </div> 
    </div><% end %>
   <div id="error_explanation">     

<%= @user.errors.full_messages.first if @user.errors.any? %>

 </div>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

log:

```
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `encrypted_password`
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_salt`
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "password_salt", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 26 Oct 2011 23:40:03 UTC +00:00], ["email", "fdfdfdfdfdffdf@sdsd.sdd"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$vFOoxHfvc3N2jNPMgx3iN.cNrxENvO5qAaSTaUa5itmzb0uADV9ZS"], ["first_name", "fddffdf"], ["last_name", "dffdffddff"], ["password_salt", "$2a$10$vFOoxHfvc3N2jNPMgx3iN."], ["updated_at", Wed, 26 Oct 2011 23:40:03 UTC +00:00], ["username", "fdgdgddgfdfd"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/success
Completed 302 Found in 87ms


Started GET "/success" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-27 00:40:03 +0100
  Processing by UsersController#success as JS
Rendered users/success.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 10.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

After save the user isn't redirected to temporary success page. Am I missing something?
I also tried redirect_to 'success'

Comment: format.html { redirect_to :success }

Comment: Basically after form is filled in and I click the button it saves the users details but stays on the page and if I press it again it fails validation because of the uniqueness rule set on email, username. Basically it tries to save again.

Comment: have you set up a route for `:success` in routes.rb?

Comment: Yep:   match 'success'        => "users#success"

Comment: It would be helpful to see the log output of what *does* happen when the user submits this form

Comment: Your form is being processed as JS. If you want the redirect, then remove the `remote=>true` from your form

Comment: Then my ajax validation won't work. The page will refresh each time user submits form and there are errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple change to the controller solved my issue:

I replaced:

```
format.html { redirect_to :success }
```

with:

```
format.js { render :js => "window.location = '#{success_path}'" }
```

all is working fine now.

Decided to not bother with recaptcha for now

Comment: this feels a touch hacky, but I had a similar problem with submitting a jquery modal form that required remote = true.  I had the similar problem where redirect was working but the format was JS in the show function of the controller, so this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

From reading your logs, your form is being processed as JS. If you want the redirect, then remove the remote=>true from your form for now

The rest is my original answer, it may be an idea to implement some of it anyway:

---

I think you need `redirect_to success_path`

UPDATE:

ok, this will work, (hopefully):

1- in routes.rb do the following:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'success'
  end
end
```

In User controller, create a new action called success

```
def success
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

In Create action

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])     
  respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to success_user_path(@user) }  
  else
    format.html { render :new }  
    format.js   { render :form_errors }
  end
end
```

Then create `/views/users/success.html.erb` (or haml) and put whatever you want in it

Comment: OK, I updated it (note that I've updated the redirect_to in create action)